# is it possible to serialize a $_FILES?

Tags: php, upload

i need to mimic how an upload form work. i need to store a file into database and uploads the $_FILES into our folders. The problem every bit of code of the models and the form itself is based on legacy code. I don't have the the gut to strip all code and start over. I prefer to let it be

So, my goal is how to uplaod file without use the previous form and then only serialize/unserialize an object consist of filename and url. while the file itself have been story via copy function and not uploads form.

Comment: `$_FILES` doesn't actually store the file itself, just the file's original name, temporary location on the server's file system, mime-type, size, and an error code if the upload failed (which would also make most of the other fields blank).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only critical part of the $_FILES array for any particular request is the `...['tmp_name']` portion, since that points to where PHP saved the uploaded file. Save a copy of a $_FILES that's set up the way you want to test (with however many files you want), then manually change the tmp_name to point to actual files on your server, rather than the random garbage names that PHP autoassigns to uploads, and you could be able to reuse a copy of the data as many times as you want, as long as your scripts don't move/delete/munge the files you're pointing at.

So, something like:

```
$_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'] = '/path/to/file/to/test/with';
$_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'] = '/some/other/path/or/file/for/testing';

$savedfiles = serialize($_FILES);
```

and then you can stick a

```
$_FILES = unserialize($savedfiles);
```

wherever it's appropriate for testing your app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to serialize $_FILES array;

```
$upload = serialize($_FILES["file"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code is dependent on the contents of the `$_FILES` variable then yes, assigning to it (whether the contents are from a serialised version in a database or wherever) should have the expected behaviour.

Generally speaking, contriving a small test is a much better way of finding out if something will work for your particular situation than asking people on the internet to speculate.